# sed replace string with string containing dash in all files in folder

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In all files in a fodler, I am trying to replace all strings of the type:

```
load(alpha)
```

to

```
load(alpha, lib="lib=~/project-a/alpha")
```

using sed I tried:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/load(alpha)/load(alpha, lib="lib=~/project-a/alpha")/g'
```

But I get the error: 
sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unknown option to `s'

Any idea what I am missing?
Thank you!

Comment: since your expression contains `/` you should use a different delimiter, say `;`

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because the `/` delimiters  with the substitute command are conflicting with the directory separators in your replacement; after the first directory separator is encountered, sed considers the replacement aborted. Change your delimiter to something else for a more clearer command.

```
sed -i 's!load(alpha)!load(alpha, lib="lib=~/project-a/alpha")!g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/load(alpha)/load(alpha, lib="lib=~\/project-a\/alpha")/g'
```

In your command the character `/` is tehe delimiter, so you need to escape any forward-slashes that are part of your data as in `/project-a/alpha` -> `\/project-a\/alpha`

Alternatively you can a different delimiter (in this case the `#` character)

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's#load(alpha)#load(alpha, lib="lib=~/project-a/alpha")#g'
```